# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My below query is causing an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.

```
Select top 1 
    a.mkey, emp_received, a.mkey, 
    c.type_desc DOC_TYPE, a.doc_no INWARD_NO, 
    c.type_desc dept_received, c.type_desc EMP_RECEIVED,   
    convert(varchar, a.doc_date, 103) date,   
    a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No, c.type_desc,   
    e.emp_name NAME, 
    ISNULL(e.Email_Id_Official, 'abc@test.com') EMAILID   
from 
    inward_doc_tracking_hdr a 
left join 
    type_mst_a c on a.doc_type = c.master_mkey 
                 and 
left join 
    type_mst_a c on a.dept_received = c.master_mkey 
left join 
    emp_mst e on a.emp_received = e.mkey  
where 
    a.emp_received is not null   
    and a.mkey = (select mkey 
                  from inward_doc_tracking_hdr aa 
                  where doc_no='IW/16/97')
```

I don't know why it is causing that error

**As per gordon's answer, I added one more left join for emp_received, but it is not working**

```
Select top 1 a.mkey, 
            cd.type_desc as DOC_TYPE,  a.doc_no as INWARD_NO,
           cr.type_desc as DEPT_RECEIVED, qr.type_desc as EMP_RECEIVED,   
           convert(varchar(255), a.doc_date,103) as date,
           a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No, 
           e.emp_name as NAME, 
           coalesce(e.Email_Id_Official, 'test@test.com') EMAILID   
    from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a left join
         type_mst_a cd
         on a.doc_type = cd.master_mkey left join
         type_mst_a cr     
         on a.emp_received = qr.master_mkey left join
         type_mst_a st
         on a.dept_received = cr.master_mkey left join
         emp_mst e
         on a.emp_received = e.mkey 
    where a.emp_received is not null and 
          a.mkey = (select mkey
                    from inward_doc_tracking_hdr aa
                    where doc_no = 'IW/16/97'
                   );
```

Comment: `and left join`:  that is not a SQL construct.

Comment: By removing `and` still getting error

Comment: That's because of `left join type_mst_a cr on a.emp_received = qr.master_mkey`. You are referring to `qr`, you probably mean `cr`. (See Gordon's code.)

Comment: @HoneyBadger: tried with `cr` too still not working.

Comment: Please be more specific. What does 'not working' mean? Do you get an error? If so, what is your error? I don't have a crystal ball telling me how your query runs.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: both the columns, dept_received and emp_received is coming NULL but they contrain values

Comment: Can you post the actual query, which run's without syntax error's but returns the unexpected data? And add some sample data and expected output, if you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113334/discussion-between-n-k-and-honeybadger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the query you want is more like this:

```
Select top 1 a.mkey,emp_received , 
       a.mkey, cd.type_desc as DOC_TYPE,  a.doc_no as INWARD_NO,
       cr.type_desc as dept_received, cr.type_desc as EMP_RECEIVED,   
       convert(varchar(255), a.doc_date,103) as date,
       a.to_user, a.No_of_pages, Ref_No, 
       e.emp_name as NAME, 
       coalesce(e.Email_Id_Official, 'test@test.com') as EMAILID   
from inward_doc_tracking_hdr a left join
     type_mst_a cd
     on a.doc_type = cd.master_mkey left join
     type_mst_a cr
     on a.dept_received = cr.master_mkey left join
     emp_mst e
     on a.emp_received = e.mkey 
where a.emp_received is not null and 
      a.mkey = (select mkey
                from inward_doc_tracking_hdr aa
                where doc_no = 'IW/16/97'
               );
```

Notes:

- The immediate problem is `and left join`.  The `and` causes a syntax error.
- You have two tables with the same alias.  That is not allowed.
- You need to be careful about which columns come from which tables; I made a good guess.
- Whenever you use `varchar()` in SQL Server, always include a length.  The default length varies by context, and if you are lazy, you will probably just suffer a hard-to-debug error at some point.
- Use `as` when defining column aliases.

Comment: I want to add one more desc for `emp_recevied` so can I add that before `on a.doc_type = cd.master_mkey left join
     type_mst_a cr`

Comment: see my question for more update, i tried for one more parameter but it is not working

Comment: @NK . . . I'm not sure what the new query is supposed to be doing.  You should have asked a new question.